# ¿Porque tengo conflicto al hacer merge de una rama "temporal"?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge

Un caso muy simple que no entiendo porque me da conflicto. Tengo un repositorio con dos ramas "master" y "develop". 
En master el fichero "version.txt" contiene el texto "1.0"

```
$ git checkout master  
$ cat version.txt 
1.0
```

En develop :

```
$ git checkout develop
$ cat version.txt
1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

El ejemplo más simple no hay cambios en el repositorio salvo el incremento de version. Es decir la secuencia seria:

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git checkout -b develop-to-master
$ echo "1.1" > version.txt
$ git add . 
$ git commit -m "Release v1.1"
$ git checkout master
$ git merge develop-to-master
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in version.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

No entiendo porque aparece el conflicto y como deberia de evitarse. La idea es que la creación de una release nueva se hace a través de un pull request de una rama *"temporal"* , pero haciéndolo siguiendo este método me causa conflicto.

```sh
* (master) v1.0
|\
|  * (develop) v1.1-SNAPSHOT
|  |
|  * (develop-to-master) v1.1
| /
* ----> Conflicto
```

---

EDITO: Amplio el caso de uso completo, espero que ahora quede claro el caso.

```
git init
git checkout -b master
echo "v1.0" > version.txt && git add . && git commit -m "v1.0"
git checkout -b develop
echo "v1.1-SNAPSHOT" > version.txt && git add . && git commit -m "v1.1-SNAPSHOT"
# ---- En este punto tengo dos ramas iniciales. 
git checkout -b develop-to-master-1.1
echo "v1.1" > version.txt && git add . && git commit -m "v1.1"
git checkout master
git merge develop-to-master-1.1
git branch -D develop-to-master-1.1
# -----  Ahora mismo tengo una versión relase de 1.1 desde develop usando
#        una rama temporal. Sin conflicto. 
#        (el merge se hace después de un pull-request)
git checkout develop
git checkout -b "new-1.2-snapshot"
echo "v1.2-SNAPSHOT" > version.txt && git add . && git commit -m "v1.2-SNAPSHOT"
git checkout develop
git merge new-1.2-snapshot 
# ---- He incrementado la versión develop tambien usando una rama temporal
#      (tambien desde un pull request)
git checkout -b develop-to-master-v1.2
echo "v1.2" > version.txt && git add . && git commit -m "v1.2"
git add . && git commit -m "v1.2"
git checkout master
git merge develop-to-master-v1.2 
# !!! Aqui ya hay conflicto
Auto-merging version.txt 
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in version.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.



*  (develop-to-master-v1.2) v1.2 
*  (new-1.2-snapshot, develop) v1.2-SNAPSHOT
| * (HEAD -> master) v1.1 
|/
*  v1.1-SNAPSHOT 
*  v1.0
```

---

EDIT 2:

Basándome en la idea de los comentarios la única opción parece ser hacer lo siguiente, pero me resulta extraño que sea la única forma:

```
git checkout develop 
git checkout -b temporal-v2.0
echo "v2.0" > version.txt && git add . && git commit -m "v2.0"
# ---------- Creo un pull request a master desde esta rama temporal
# Creo tambien una rama para integrar en develop desde esta misma rama temporal
git checkout -b from-temporal-v2.0-to-develop
echo "v2.1-SN" > version.txt && git add . && git commit -m "v2.1-SN"                                                                                                                    
# ----------- Creo un pull request para develop.
```

El merge ahora no da conflicto. Pero si durante el pull request hay algún cambio en las ramas, en el futuro volverá a causar conflicto.

Comment: El conflicto no está dando en version.txt, sino en file.txt. Tendrías que poner más bien la historia del fichero file.txt para ver por qué da conflicto.

Comment: Creo que en ningún sitio he puesto file.txt, en cualquier caso es un error tipográfico. Siempre me refiero al mismo fichero version.txt

Comment: Si, si que has puesto file.txt: CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file.txt. De todas formas, ahora con el ejemplo completo se ve mejor lo que quieres preguntar.

Comment: Ok, cierto. Lo corrijo, gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El resultado de los comandos que has puesto después de la edición es este:

[image: arbol de git]

El motivo por el que te da conflicto es que desde el punto en el que se abren las dos ramas (rama roja y rama verde) se ha modificado en ambas ramas una sección de código muy cercana (en este caso el fichero entero ya que es un fichero muy pequeño)

Desde el punto en que se abren las dos ramas el fichero cambia así:

```
rama roja:  v1.1-SNAPSHOT cambia a v1.1
rama verde: v1.1-SNAPSHOT cambia a V1.2
```

Git no puede saber con qué te quieres quedar y te hace elegir una de las dos. Esto no te hubiera pasado por ejemplo si no hubieses creado el commit `v1.1`. y hubieses mergeado `develop-to-master-v1.2` cuando `master` apuntaba a `v1.1-SNAPSHOT`. Tampoco te hubiera pasado si el fichero `version.txt` fuese más grande y en cada una de las ramas se hubiese modificado una parte de un fichero que no afectase a la otra.

Como norma general, si estás siguiendo las recomendaciones de git-flow, si es posible en `master` no se deberían crear commits sueltos, sino que solo debería recibir mergeos de la rama `hotfix` y `release`.

https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

EDIT: En teoría, el incremento de versión debería ocurrir en la rama release o en la rama hotfix porque estás "preparando" una nueva versión en esas ramas. Si tu subes a producción una versión 1.0, en cuanto empiezes a trabajar en develop estarás por ejemplo preparando una versión 2.0. Si mientras estás trabajando en la 2.0 surje un problema importante en producción, se prepararía un fix para la 1.1 que ocurriría antes de mergear la futura 2.0. Antes de mergear en master, puedes crear un commit en estas ramas para incrementar la versión. Yo suelo hacerlo en cuanto mergeo en master, incremento la versión de las ramas que he mergeado. Así cuando estoy ejecutando código de esa rama sé que estoy trabajando en una versión más nueva que la que hay en producción. Te pego una imagen con tres puntos donde puedes incrementar la versión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lógicamente esto depende de tu proyecto y como trabajes con tu equipo, git-flow es simplemente una recomendación. Lo que pasa es que si lo vas a hacer como indicas en la pregunta no te va a quedar otra que resolver los conflictos.

EDIT2: Por último añadir, que la resolución de conflictos es una parte intrínseca de usar git (en general resolver conflicto es una habilidad más del programador como saber depurar). Veo últimamente que es común darle demasiada importancia a que algo que hacemos en git dé un conflicto. Hay gente que tiene la concepción de que si solo estoy trabajando yo, no debería tener conflictos nunca. Esto es erróneo, un conflicto te puede dar por muchos motivos, por mergear ramas, por hacer rebase, por sacar datos del stash... Al final el conflicto nos ayuda notar un punto donde puede haber un problema en el que podemos perder código, no es necesariamente que estemos haciendo algo mal.

Comment: Ok, pero en el caso de que el repositorio contenga un fichero que indica la version (pom.xml, version.txt, version.rc ... ) Si quiero mantener este fichero con versiones diferentes en develop y master (-SNAPSHOT, -RELEASE ) debo de tener un commit intermedio para hacer merge, y obligatorio si todos los merge a develop / master deben de pasar por un pull request y un proceso de validacion.

Comment: Te contesto en la respuesta que no me cabe xD

Comment: Impaciente estoy :D

Comment: He añadido una imagen para aclarar sitios posibles donde puedes incrementar la versión sin que te de conflicto y que te van a indicar cuando hagas checkout a esas ramas en que versión real del código estás.

Comment: Claro, pero la diferencia está en que v0.2 (y v2.0) el contenido es el mismo en develop y master. Pero hay un fichero de versión que tiene contenido diferente para master  y para develop. Añado a la descripción inicial una ampliación  con lo que comentas.

Comment: Ok, después de hacer varias pruebas creo que entiendo.La rama temporal es lo que se hace usando el git flow : 
```
git flow release start 1.0
```
Internamente hace lo mismo que yo digo, muchas gracias por la pista.

Answer (score 3):

La explicación que encuentro es que tu recuerdo de cómo ocurrieron las cosas esté equivocado, pues tal como lo has descrito no podría haber conflicto. Un escenario similar (pero diferente) en el que sí ocurriría conflicto sería:

- En la rama `master` hay un fichero `version.txt` con un contenido cualquiera, desconocido a partir de tu descripción (pongamos `v?.?`)
- Se crea la rama `develop`
- En la rama `master` se cambia el contenido de `version.txt` a `v1.0` y se hace *commit*.
- En la rama `develop` se cambia la versión a `v1.1-SNAPSHOT` y se hace *commit*.
- Se crea una nueva rama `develop-to-master`, se cambia la versión a `v1.1` y se hace *commit*
- Se vuelve a la rama `master`, se intenta un *merge* de `develop-to-master` y se encuentra un conflicto.

Es decir, el diagrama de flujo sería:

```
* (master) v?.?
|\
| \
*  \  (master)   v1.0
|   * (develop)  v1.1-SNAPSHOT
|   |
|   * (develop-to-master) v1.1
|  /
| /
* ----> Conflicto
```

Un conflicto se produce cuando un fichero ha sido modificado en dos ramas, de forma diferente en cada una. En este escenario que planteo, el fichero `version.txt` habría sido modificado en la rama `master` y también en la rama `develop`, por lo que en el *merge* git no tendría claro cuál de las ramas tiene la versión "definitiva".

El escenario que tú planteas en cambio no puede producir conflicto porque los cambios sólo habrían ocurrido en una rama (la rama master no habría tenido más modificaciones desde la creación de la rama `develop`). En esta situación el merge sería un simple *fast-forward* (la referencia `main`  se movería al final de la otra rama).

Comment: Creo que no entiendo, el conflicto existe pero puesto que el fichero solo se modifica en las versiones "develop" y  las temporales para preparar la release y se hace de forma separada a master

Comment: Perdón por editar el comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Fernando, el problema es que cuando tienes una rama de liberación (release) y terminas el trabajo en ella, la debes integrar a la rama master **y también a la *develop***.

De allí en adelante, sigues trabajando en tu nueva versión en la rama develop y sus subramas "feature", si es necesario.

```
# ---- En este punto tengo dos ramas iniciales. 
git checkout -b develop-to-master-1.1
echo "v1.1" > version.txt && git add . && git commit -m "v1.1"
git checkout master
git merge develop-to-master-1.1
# **************** DEBES INTEGRAR TAMBIÉN A develop *******
git checkout develop
git merge develop-to-master-1.1
# *********************************************************
git branch -D develop-to-master-1.1
# -----  Ahora mismo tengo una versión relase de 1.1 desde develop usando
#        una rama temporal. Sin conflicto. 
#        (el merge se hace después de un pull-request)
git checkout develop
git checkout -b "new-1.2-snapshot"
```

---

**¿Por qué el conflicto?**

Si vemos el log:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate
* f1ce09e (develop-to-master-v1.2) v1.2
* ea136af (new-1.2-snapshot, develop) v1.2-SNAPSHOT
| * b44d5c2 (HEAD -> master, develop-to-master-1.1) v1.1
|/  
* a5824f8 v1.1-SNAPSHOT
* b73f55c v1.0
```

Quires hacer un merge entre el commit L (`b44d`) y el commit R (`f1ce`), cuyo ancestro común es el commit B (`a582`).

Revisando el estado del archivo `version.txt` en los commits tenemos esto:

- Commit B: "v1.1-SNAPSHOT"
- Commit L: "v1.1"
- Commit R: "v1.2"

Así, cuando `git` intenta hacer el merge se da cuenta que el archivo ha sido modificado en las 2 ramas y no puede saber cuál es la versión que debe conservar.

---

Respecto a los "pull-requests", la mayoría de veces estos son usados para solicitar al dueño de un repositorio que incluya los cambios que tu has hecho en tu copia del repositorio, o para solicitarle al administrador de un repositorio en el que no tienes permisos, que incluya los cambios de una rama tuya.

En mi opinion los pull-requests deben realizarse únicamente hacia ramas de desarrollo (o release, en el caso de pequeños arreglos, o master en caso de Hot-fixes), así el desarrollador debe asegurarse que sus cambios son compatibles y están en sincronía con el repo principal, y el dueño/admin debe realizar las pruebas, aprobar su integración e incorporar esos cambios a las demas ramas, Master, develop o release.

Comment: Basandome en tu idea he editado mi pregunta inicial, con tu ejemplo no puedo trabajar usando pull-request, que es mi forma de trabajar.

Comment: @FernandoRosado, he actualizado la respuesta y dejado una opinión, espero te pueda servir.

Comment: pregunta: que problema tienes que haya conflicto? Los conflictos se van a dar si tienes mucha gente trabajando sobre el mismos proyecto y el mismo fichero. En caso de conflicto, se tiene que integrar y resolver manualmente. Quiero decir, NO ES MALO que de conflictos (otra cosa es que den siempre sin saber por que)

Comment: @Jakala ese es el problema, diferentes equipos de trabajo trabajando sobre el mismo repositorio, los conflictos aparecen cada vez que se hace el proceso de liberar la release. Al tener que mantener una version SNAPSHOT en develop y otra release dentro de master y al obligar como parte del workflow que la integración a estas ramas se haga siempre a través de un pull request.

Comment: @gustavovelascoh también es posible que la integración de una rama a develop y master solo se pueda hacer si pasa primero por un pull request, bitbucket por ejemplo tiene esa opción. Para equipos medianamente grandes es una forma de asegurarse de que haya un conocimiento de en se está trabajando y que los cambios de uno no eche por tierra el de otro. En culaquier caso creo que ya me ha quedado claro que mi forma de verlo no encaja con la forma de trabajar de git. Muchas gracias.